# The difference between MSK as CPFSK and OQPSK

Tags: digital-communications, modulation, qpsk, fsk

I am working on MSK simulation. I have read the Chapter 5 of book entitled *Digital Modulation Techniques* by Fuqin Xiong. It is said that MSK can be viewed as a Sinusoidal Weighted OQPSK or CPFSK. If we write the MSK signal as

$$
s(t)=A\cos\left(2\pi f_c t + d_k \frac{\pi t}{2T} + \phi_k\right), \quad kT\leq t\leq (k+1)T 
$$

From the first perspective (MSK as a Sinusoidal Weighted OQPSK), we have
$$
d_k=I_kQ_k , \quad \phi_k=\frac{\pi}{2}(1-I_k) 
$$

From the second perspective (MSK as CPFSK), we have
$$
d_k=d_{k-1}\newcommand*\xor{\mathbin{\oplus}}a_k,  \quad \phi_k=\frac{\pi}{2}\left(\sum_{i=0}^{k-1}d_i-kd_k\right) 
$$
where $\{a_k\}$ represents the original data stream and $\newcommand*\xor{\mathbin{\oplus}}$ is XOR. I have the following question:

- Are the two methods for computing MSK and specifically $\phi_k$ equivalent?
- Do they result in the same MSK signal?

In my simulations, the two MSK signals that I get from these two perspectives don't have the same phase.

Comment: I might try to formulate an answer later on; in the meantime have a look at [this post](http://mattsdsp.blogspot.co.at/2015/01/minimum-shift-keying-msk-and-its.html) explaining the relation between MSK and OQPSK.

Comment: One of the best tutorials on MSK as OQPSK with sinusoidal pulse shapes or as CPFSK is by S. Pasupathy in the _IEEE Communications Magazine_ August 1979. Unfortunately, it is presumably behind IEEE's paywall and thus inaccessible to many, but a readable copy can be found on the _[Researchgate](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/3197120_Minimum_Shift_Keying_A_Spectrally_Efficient_Modulation)_ website.

Answer (score 4):

The answer to your question is yes, these two representations are equivalent. The first important thing to note is that in your formula, $d_k$ must be either $1$ or $-1$, because the frequency difference for MSK must be $\Delta f=1/2T$.

I'll add some information showing the equivalence of the two representations. Expanding your first formula gives

$$\begin{align}s(t)&=A\cos\left(2\pi f_ct+d_k\frac{\pi t}{2T}+\phi_k\right)\\&=A\left[\cos(2\pi f_ct)\cos\left(d_k\frac{\pi t}{2T}+\phi_k\right)-\sin(2\pi f_ct)\sin\left(d_k\frac{\pi t}{2T}+\phi_k\right)\right]\\&=A\left[\cos(2\pi f_ct)\cos\left(d_k\frac{\pi t}{2T}\right)\cos(\phi_k)-\sin(2\pi f_ct)\sin\left(d_k\frac{\pi t}{2T}\right)\cos(\phi_k)\right]\\&=A\left[\cos(2\pi f_ct)\cos\left(\frac{\pi t}{2T}\right)\cos(\phi_k)-\sin(2\pi f_ct)\sin\left(\frac{\pi t}{2T}\right)d_k\cos(\phi_k)\right]\\&=A\left[\cos(2\pi f_ct)\cos\left(\frac{\pi t}{2T}\right)I_k-\sin(2\pi f_ct)\sin\left(\frac{\pi t}{2T}\right)Q_k\right]\tag{1}\end{align}$$

with

$$I_k=\cos(\phi_k)\quad\text{and}\quad Q_k=d_k\cos(\phi_k)\tag{2}$$

where I've used $\cos(a+b)=\cos(a)\cos(b)-\sin(a)\sin(b)$, $\sin(a+b)=\cos(a)\sin(b)+\sin(a)\cos(b)$, the fact that $\sin(\phi_k)=0$ (because $\phi_k\in\{0,\pi\})$, and the fact that $d_k\in\{1,-1\}$.

Equation $(1)$ shows that the MSK signal $s(t)$ can be represented as a QPSK signal with in-phase component $I_k$ and quadrature component $Q_k$ with sinusoidal pulse shaping. In this [blog post](http://mattsdsp.blogspot.co.at/2015/01/minimum-shift-keying-msk-and-its.html), it is shown that $I_k$ and $Q_k$ can never change at the same time, and both of them change with a rate $1/2T$. That's why this type of modulation is called *offset* QPSK (OQPSK). All this is related to the phase recursion shown in Eq. $(3)$ below.

In order for the MSK signal to have a continuous phase, the phase $\phi_k$ must satisfy the following recurrence relation:

$$\phi_k=\phi_{k-1}+(d_{k-1}-d_k)\frac{k\pi}{2}\qquad(\text{mod } 2\pi)\tag{3}$$

This relation is also derived in the above mentioned [post](http://mattsdsp.blogspot.co.at/2015/01/minimum-shift-keying-msk-and-its.html) (Eq. $(7)$). Note that the formula for $\phi_k$ in your question satisfies $(3)$. However, it's probably easier to directly use the recursion $(3)$. From $(3)$ it follows that

$$\phi_k=\begin{cases}\phi_{k-1}\pm\pi,&k\text{ odd and }d_k\neq d_{k-1}\\\phi_{k-1},&\text{otherwise}\end{cases}\tag{4}$$

From $(4)$ it is clear that $\phi_k$ changes with a rate $1/2T$.

Finally, inverting $(2)$, i.e., expressing $d_k$ and $\phi_k$ in terms of $I_k$ and $Q_k$, is straightforward:

$$I_kQ_k=d_k\cos^2(\phi_k)=d_k\tag{5}$$

because $\cos(\phi_k)$ can only be $1$ or $-1$. Furthermore, $1-\cos(\phi_k)$ equals $0$ for $\phi_k=0$ and $2$ for $\phi_k=\pi$. Consequently,

$$\phi_k=\frac{\pi}{2}(1-I_k)\tag{6}$$

Both Equations $(5)$ and $(6)$ are correctly stated in your question.

In sum, all your formulas appear to be correct. You haven't shown your formulas for $I_k$ and $Q_k$; they should be equivalent to Eq. $(2)$. I have the suspicion that your $d_k$ are either $1$ or $0$. As mentioned above, they should be either $1$ or $-1$, otherwise $s(t)$ is no valid MSK signal. Also note that the mapping between the information bits and $d_k$ is totally irrelevant for all derivations shown above.

---

EDIT: In analogy with Eq. $(4)$, you can derive recursions for $I_k$ and $Q_k$ from Eqs. $(2)$ and $(3)$:

$$I_k=\begin{cases}-I_{k-1},&k\text{ odd and }d_k\neq d_{k-1}\\I_{k-1},&\text{otherwise}\end{cases}\tag{7}$$

$$Q_k=\begin{cases}-Q_{k-1},&k\text{ even and }d_k\neq d_{k-1}\\Q_{k-1},&\text{otherwise}\end{cases}\tag{8}$$

Choosing an initial phase $\phi_0=0$ results in the initial values $I_0=1$ and $Q_0=d_0$.
From $(7)$ and $(8)$ it is obvious that $I_k$ and $Q_k$ never change at the same time, hence *offset* QPSK.

Comment: Thank you Matt for your comprehensive response. I would like to say that I have $d_k$ as 1 or -1. In Matlab, I have used $I_k=d_k$(2:2:end) and $Q_k=d_k$(1:2:end). I still don't know why the signals generated from two methods do not have the same phase always. Moreover, they also have a different phase compared with the MSK signal generated by Matlab's ${comm.MSKModulator }$ object and ${step}$ function.

Comment: @Cror2014: You must define $I_k$ and $Q_k$ according to Eq. $(2)$; they also depend on the phase $\phi_k$. If you implement it as shown in my answer you should get the same result for CPFSK and OQPSK.

Comment: Based on what you are saying, I should first compute $\phi_k$ and  then $I_k$ and $Q_k$; You're right. This way the results should be the same. But, I think it should be possible to get $I_k$ and $Q_k$ directly from $d_k$ and then delay $Q_k$ one bit time. Because this is one of the modulator implementations shown in the book ${Digital Modulation Techniques}$ by Fuqin Xiong. In that, the data stream is converted to parallel and then $I_k$ and $Q_k$ is extracted. Other than this, as I said, the signal that I generate by either approaches, does not match the one generated by Matlab!!

Comment: @Cror2014: I've added recursion formulas for $I_k$ and $Q_k$ to my answer. As for the comparison with Matlab, you need to figure out how they map the information bits to $d_k$.