# Continuous Phase Modulation

Tags: digital-communications, modulation

The [wikipedia article on continuous-phase modulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_phase_modulation) states the following:

> For instance, with QPSK the carrier instantaneously jumps from a sine to a cosine (i.e. a 90 degree phase shift) whenever one of the two message bits of the current symbol differs from the two message bits of the previous symbol. This discontinuity requires a relatively large percentage of the power to occur outside of the intended band (e.g., high fractional out-of-band power), leading to poor spectral efficiency.

I want to know how this is true since in M-ary PSK the amplitude is constant so isn't the power constant too?

Comment: The power is constant but the phase is not.

Answer (score 1):

What is important is the envelope of the modulated signal. For M-PSK, due to the phase discontinuities, the envelope droops every time there is a phase transition. The envelope even goes to zero if there is a phase transition of $180$ degrees. So M-PSK does not have a constant envelope.

Changes in the envelope are largely reduced by using [offset QPSK (OQPSK)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phase-shift_keying#Offset_QPSK_(OQPSK)), and they are completely eliminated by using [continuous-phase modulation schemes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_phase_modulation), such as [minimum-shift keying (MSK)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimum-shift_keying), which is a special case of OQPSK.

Take a look at these related questions and its answers: [Q1](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/q/56669/4298), [Q2](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/q/33856/4298), [Q3](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/q/51220/4298).